# Array of XML files in JS

Tags: javascript, xml

I want to read xml files from a folder using JS. I would like to do it dynamically that even if you add some files later the JS must detect the file and read it. 
Basically i want to make an array of xml files dynamically.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You need some service on the server that gives you the list of files. You cannot read the content of a directory with JS alone.

Comment: is the folder client side or server side?

Answer (score 0):

I've wanted to do something very similar for a while.

The most "dynamic" method of doing this myself so far is to have server-side script (such as PHP) scan through the files of a directory and output them to JavaScript/HTML.

You could of course have an XML files detailing the XML files, but of course this would require manual editing of the XML File List when a new XML was placed in the directory.

Comment: Hi colinccook, if you know, how can i read some number of xml files in a folder locally using JS using an array.

Comment: Browsers can't read contents of a filesystem with JavaScript. JavaScript is stuck inside the browser, primarily for security reasons.